# no muestra coincidencias JQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

Estoy usando la libreria de autocomplete de Jquery creo que ya funciona 50%, no me genera error pero no me muestra el texto de las coincidencias que encuentra, solo me aparecen como que las filas de donde debe de ir el texto, no se ¿ por que ?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
          $.ajax({
              type:"post",
          url: "coincidencia",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="city">Buscar </label>
  <input id="city">
</div>
```

En la pagina coincidencia genero una cadena JSON

```html
@Code
    Dim valor = Request.Form("q")
    
    Dim queryBusca = db.Query("SELECT nombre FROM ADENDA WHERE nombre LIKE'" + valor + "%' GROUP BY nombre")

End Code

 [
    @Code 
        Dim i = 1
        For Each item In queryBusca End Code      
             { "nombre":"@item("razon_social")"
    @Code If i <> queryBusca.Count Then End code
          },
    @code Else end code
          }
    @code            
          End If
    End Code
    @code        
         i = i + 1
         Next 
    End Code
]
```

Los resultados que regresa mi pagina coincidencia
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Veo que te decidiste por usar el [`Autocomplete jQuery UI`](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33894/16597). Si pudieras agregar el JSON que devuelve podemos ver de agregar lo que le falta a tu código.

Comment: @Marcos Gallardo ya he colocado la imagen con los resultados que devuelve la pagina coincidencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[La documentación dice](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/):

> There are two supported formats:
>
> 1. An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> 2. An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

Prueba hacer este cambio:

```
success: function( data ) {
  var formatted = [];

  $.each(data, function(index, info) {
    formatted.push(info.nombre);
  });
  response(formatted);
}
```

La razón por la cual muestra una lista de registros, pero vacia, es porque el `autocomplete` espera un arreglo de cadenas *(formato 1)* o un arreglo de objetos con propiedades `label` y `value` *(formato 2)*. Lo que actualmente le estas pasando al llamar `response` era un arreglo de objetos con 1 propiedad `nombre`

Comment: si funciono pero no entendí por que no parecian

Comment: @lvxn simplemente magia pura

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer al devolver un objeto debes modificar :

```
success: function(data) {

    response($.map(data, function(item) {
        return {
           label: item.nombre,
           value: item.nombre,
        }
    }));
}
```

Ya que tu devuelves un objeto con indice `0 {nombre}` por lo que creo que tu `autocomplete` si se llena, pero no de la manera correcta.

Comment: me ayudo tu respuesta gracias

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funcionó de esta forma pero en Laravel, aun así creo que en la vista se crea igual, solo cambia RUTA por la ruta que recibe tu petición.

```
$(function(){
      $('#txtCampo').autocomplete({
        source: 'RUTA',
        minLength:3,
        select: function(event,ui){
          $('#txtCampo').val(ui.item.value);
        }
      });
      $('#txtCampo').data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul,item){
        var $li = $('');
        $li.attr('data-value',item.value);
        $li.append(""+item[1]);
        console.log(item);
        return $li.appendTo(ul);
      }
    });
```